# custom colour space transformation in ffmpeg?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a custom colour space transformation command in ffmpeg?  So that I can specify where I want the corners of the colour space to move to, which might be different in different situations.

The problem i'm facing at the moment is that the colour always seems to come out slightly different.  If i use gamma correction in FFMPEG, then it translates the space, but doesn't transform or stretch the colour space triangle to fit the new colour space triangle.  Which means that for example if I match a colour by way of empirical binary search, it won't match to the other colours.

Also, i can't seem to find a pre-defined colour space transformation in FFMPEG that matches the colour swatches I have.

I'd like to try and automate transformation of colour space in video by way of optimisation, so that it finds the corners of the colour space for me based on how it renders out, and what colour is expected, and was wondering if something like this is possible... ?

Thanks in advance for any insight or suggestions regarding this.

Comment: Share what your specific requirement is + full command. How are you viewing the input / output?

Comment: I want to be able to sample the colours in the colours of a video locally on my machine, then sample the colours after they are rendered in the cloud, and then adapt the colour space so that what I see locally is what is rendered in the cloud.

If i use a pre-defined colour space transformation, there is no guarantee that the colour will be correct at the end of the line.  It might be that at the end of the line the colour space is different.

Is there a way to specify the values of the affine colour transformation matrix rather than using pre-defined transforms in FFMPEG ?